# mongodb aggregate two collections and add new fields

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I have two collections: **authors** and **books**

**author example:**

```
{
   _id: "605f6746c114544ee04228bd"
   firstName: "firstName",
   lastName: "lastName",
}
```

**book example:**

```
{
   _id: "605f6746c114544ee04228bd"
   title: "title",
   pages: 350,
}
```

**I want to get the list of books with thier author firstName and lastName.**

here is my current code:

```
let books;

books = await Book.find();
books.forEach(async (book, i) => {
  const author = await Author.findOne(
    { _id: book.authorId },
    { firstName: 1, lastName: 1, _id: 0 }
  );
  books[i].authorFirstName = author.firstName;
  books[i].authorLastName = author.lastName;
});
```

This is not a good practice because for each book I execut another request to mongodb database!
Any better solution?

Comment: Use `mongoose.populate`, it is the way of linking two models together

Comment: Thank you @Mastermind it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mongoose version to join two models with relationship

```
books = await Book.find({}).populate({ path:"authorId", select:{firstName:1, lastName:1}})
```

> Using aggregation

```
let books = await Book.aggregation([
   { 
     $lookup:{
        from:"collection_of_author",
        localField: "authorId",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "author"
     }
   },
  {
    $unwind: {
       path:"authorId",
       preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true 
    }
  }])
```

Answer (score 1):

**Clean code and higher performance using mongoose populate**

```
  import Book from "../models/Book";
  import Author from "../models/Author";

  let books = await Book.find().populate({
    path: "authorId",
    model: Author,
    select: { firstName: 1, lastName: 1, _id: 0 },
  });
```